# Call windows explorer to refresh recycle bin filename

Tags: c, winapi, filenames, redraw, recycle-bin

I changed recycle bin name by this code:

```
HKEY recycleBinHKey;
LPCSTR registrySubkey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\CLSID\\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}";
const BYTE * pnewValue = (const BYTE *) "СибАДИ";
int newValueLen = 7;

RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, registrySubkey, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &recycleBinHKey);
RegSetValueExA(recycleBinHKey, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, pnewValue, newValueLen);
RegCloseKey(recycleBinHKey);
```

I need to call explorer to refresh desktop, so new filename is visible. Is there any function in winapi that can help me?
I'm using Windows 10

I've tried

`RedrawWindow(NULL, NULL, NULL, RDW_INTERNALPAINT);`

and

`SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ALLEVENTS, SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, NULL, NULL);`

but there is no required result - recycle bin name didn't change.

Comment: Have you tried just `SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED` instead of `SHCNE_ALLEVENTS`? In any case, what makes you think you can rename the Recycle Bin in this manner to begin with? This is certainly not documented.

Comment: SHCNE_UPDATEITEM with the recycle bin pidl.

Comment: I think you got wrong directory. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong directory. Recycle bin name is not in here.
Check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}`. I'm working on win11.
[image]